# I need help understanding a circuit simplification in my textbook

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

The question I have about this problem is how to obtain the 80 kOhm equivalent resistance for the circuit attached to the conductor. What I did was I combined the 240 kohm and 60 kOhm resistors in parallel and then combined their equivalent resistance with the 32 kOhm in series but the value I obtained did not match what is described in the textbook. I also know that I cannot combine the 32 kOhm resistor with the 240 kOhm resistor in series so I am stuck on how to obtain the 80 kOhms that the book has.

Answer (score 5):

80k = 240k in parallel with 60k = 48k in series with 32k.

I assume you did something wrong in the parallel math.

Comment: Please, Trevor, small k for kilo! 'K' is for kelvin. +1 for the right answer.